# Which Netduino hardware should I use?

Tags: hardware, netduino

I am building a temporary controller that needs to monitor 20 separate button pushes along with another 15-20 analog and digital signals.

It also needs to output at least 20 different digital signals.

Which Netdurino will let me get all these different ports together on a single device?

It seems like the [Netduino Go](http://www.netduino.com/netduinogo/specs.htm)  with multiple [shield bases](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/3900-hardware-details-shield-base/) [(image)](http://www.netduino.com/images/netduinogo/accessories/secretlabs_shieldbase.jpg) is the way to go.

Can anyone confirm that this is the hardware solution I am looking for with the most analog and digital ports available?

Thank you,
Keith

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming (code) related questions, not hardware selection advice. Also, recommendation questions are specifically prohibited here as opinion-based "shopping list" questions. See the [help/on-topic] page for more information.

Comment: I would suggest trying the Engineering exchange. You will get much better answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you're settled on the Netduino platform, I'd suggest you ask either on the Netduino forums or in their live chat room http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/chat/

Alternately, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ might yield better answers than stackoverflow.

Note that in the forum post you link to for the shield base, they indicate that only one shield base is supported per Netduino (at the time of writing, this may have changed):

> > Another noob question: How many shield bases can one connect to a NGO? Is more than 1 a viable option?
>
> Currently just one. But with the final release I'm hoping on more :)